# How can I communicate between two Today widgets in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, cloudkit, today-extension

- have two today widgets.
- on `viewDidLoad` for both of them I fetch the latest data and save to core data like this:

  ```
  CloudAssistant.shared.fetchServicesForCurrentMonth { _ in 
      self.updateView()
  }
  ```

And here is the problem. If widgets are loaded, the same time I perform fetch from CloudKit. Records are parsed and saved to core data simultanously. So... it leads to doubled records for my **Service** entity.

I do not know how to solve this. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You have to specify App Groups in your app. App and widgets can share recources in that groups

Comment: I know, I use it currently, but it is not the case... I need to inform second widget to not to fetch, because I currently fetch services from controller that started fetching first. I think it is rather impossible...

Comment: I suppose that the only solution is to fetch from only one widget, not from both of them...